# Trying to access array offset on value of type null but can't find the right solution

Tags: php, mysqli

Good day. I'm trying to have progress in creating the Web-cart but I'm stuck on the **Trying to access array offset**. I can get rid of it so it won't show, but I need the text from my SQL database.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from product";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'] ." ". $row['name'] ." ". $row['image'] ." ". $row['price'] ." ". $row['description'] ." ". $row['type']. "<br>";
  } //This part is showing up without a problem
?>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="">
  <h3><?php echo $row['name']?></h3>
  <h6><?php echo $row['price']?></h6> //This part however is showing me Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in Line 45,46,47
</div>
```

I looked through a lot of stuff, but can't seem to get the grasp on what to change.
P.S. - Im using XAMP to look on the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are getting value of `$row` in a loop and the loop is closing before printing all its values.

Please correct To:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from product";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['id'] ." ". $row['name'] ." ". $row['image'] ." ". $row['price'] ." ". $row['description'] ." ". $row['type']. "<br>";
// `$row` was closing here, it shouldn't close here as its values are accessed below it.
?>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <img src="<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="">
  <h3><?php echo $row['name']?></h3>
  <h6><?php
  } // This needs to be moved here.
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Trying to access array offset

means that you have an array where you try to access an item which does not exist. As Pupil pointed out in his answer, you try to access stuff in your `$row` `array` outside the loop, which seems to be not what you want, but strictly technically speaking this is a different bug from that which throws the error. Nonetheless this needs to be fixed as well, as described by Pupil. After the loop `$row` is `null`, which will throw a different error.

Your issue throws the error because `$row` was created as an array successfully, but at least one of the columns you try to access with `echo` does not exist. You run a `select *` clause, so you will need to refer the structure of the table by running

```
desc product;
```

or

```
show create table product;
```

and see what the column names are, see whether the column names match the column names you try to refer in PHP in a case-sensitive manner.